# Why use AWS S3 to store static assets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, file, amazon-s3, cloud, static-assert

What's the advantage of storing static assets for your application in S3 over having them directly in your repository?

I imagine it's a combination of keeping the size of your repository small and not having it be bloated with images, media files, etc. Is there any other reason? I have a hard time understanding the necessity of storing static assets on S3.

Comment: What repository are you referring to?

Comment: The repository for any application. For example, having images located in a /static sub directory in your repo.

Comment: The advantage of using Amazon S3 comes from _serving_ content to your users, since it offloads requests from your main application servers. This is a reliability/scalability decision, rather than something to do with repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 has some properties that make it useful for serving static assets over the internet:

- Firstly, it's highly available (99.9%).
- Secondly, it's highly scalable, meaning that it can serve millions of requests at a time.
- Thirdly, when used with CloudFront it's highly performant from a client perspective, as it can securely serve content at the edge (close to the user) as well as caching content.